# Adjusting Tab visibility after creation

Tags: apex, tab

Is there a way to make a tab hidden for specific profiles after the tab is created?

When the tab is created we get to pick what the default setting needs to be and get to choose the custom apps the tab needs to be included.

I am unable to do the same on an existing tab, is there an easy way to do this/ I need to go to every profile edit and make the "Tab hidden" from all the profiles :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're out of luck. Tab settings are [unsupported in the Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm).

Comment: That's so annoying, so basic yet not available:(!!! I have 71 profiles to manage, I think I will have to delete the tab and recreate to adjust the tab visibility.

Comment: Agreed, and I would probably do the same thing.

Comment: Vote for this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HUNfAAO

Comment: I already voted for the idea :)